# ScrollViewer not scrolling

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, scrollviewer

The scrollviewer below does not work. I tried everything I could find on this site and beyond: embedding the scrollviewer in an Grid, embedding the ScrollViewer's children in a grid, embedding the Scrollviewer in a StackPanel with fixed height, setting/binding the height of the scrollviewer, all to no avail... Who shows me the way back to sanity??

Mind, the XAML below is just to show how the window is structured. I removed all the data.

```
<Window>
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ColoringLabels">
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <DockPanel>
        <StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <StatusBarItem>
            </StatusBarItem>
        </StatusBar>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBox/>
            <Button>Hello World!</Button>
            <ScrollViewer>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Label>Hola Mundo!</Label>
                    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ListBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource ColoringLabels}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                    <ListBox Source="{Binding}"ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ColoringLabels}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
            <TextBlock/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

EDIT:

I solved it by changing the XAML to:

```
<Window>
   <Window.Resources>
       <DataTemplate x:Key="ColoringLabels">
       </DataTemplate>
   </Window.Resources>
   <DockPanel>
       <StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Top">
           <StatusBarItem>
           </StatusBarItem>
       </StatusBar>
       <ScrollViewer>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBox />
                <Button>Hello World!</Button>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Label>Hola Mundo!</Label>
                        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ListBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource ColoringLabels}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListBox>
                        <ListBox Source="{Binding}"ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ColoringLabels}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                <TextBlock/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Why it is working now??? Perhaps because the ScrollViewer now gets to fill the LastChild position of the DockPanel???

Comment: i've having the same problem now and i tried your solution.But why is mine not working? Once I use my listbox with a scrollviewer, it gets messed up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication7.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="308" Width="527">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ColoringLabels">
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <StatusBar>
                <StatusBarItem>
                </StatusBarItem>
            </StatusBar>
            <TextBox/>
            <Button>Hello World!</Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <ScrollViewer>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
                <Label>Hola Mundo!</Label>
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ListBox />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
                <ListBox />
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
        <TextBlock/>
    </DockPanel>

</Window>
```

**EDIT**
Your new code is working just becouse scrollviewer size is fixed now(it's fill the free part of screen), and it is not growing outside the window when it's content is growing...

Comment: Thanks for all the work you are putting in this! I followed you earlier suggestion and added height to the first stackpanle beneath the scrollviewer (nothing happened) and gave height to the listbox. That worked, but did not produce the desired effect. I put the Scrollviewer higher up in the hierarchy and that did produce what I was looking for.

Comment: You are wellcome, I edited the post, find the answer of your last questin.

Answer (score 1):

Try to give height to your listbox or stackpanel in scrollviewer, scrollviewer scrolls when it's content is bigger than it's size  in your case when you add items to listbox, listbox's height is not growing and listbox is scrolling